# Not able to publish any item in SDL WEB 8.5

Tags: publishing, web8.5, publishtransaction

We are using SDL web 8.5 and suddenly we are having an issue while publishing any item reason is Publish Transaction is not able to save .we are getting below error inside event viewer

```
Connection request timed out
  Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 0 User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Messaging.ScaleoutStream.Send(Func`2 send, Object state)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Notifications.NotificationsManager.BroadcastNotification(NotificationMessage notification)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.CME.TcmExtensions.EventHandlers.IdentifiableObjectEventHandler(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs e, EventPhases phases)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSubscription.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventPhases phase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IEnumerable`1 subjects, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.EventSystem.DeliverEvent(IdentifiableObject subject, TcmEventArgs eventArgs, EventDeliveryPhase deliveryPhase)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs eventArgs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishTransaction.Save()
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.InternalCreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, IEnumerable`1 targetPurposes, Nullable`1 priority)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.CreatePublishTransactions(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstructionBase instruction, IEnumerable`1 targets, IEnumerable`1 targetPurposes, Nullable`1 priority)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.Publish(IEnumerable`1 items, PublishInstruction publishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targetTypes)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.Publish(IEnumerable`1 ids, PublishInstructionData publishInstruction, IEnumerable`1 targetIdsOrPurposes, Nullable`1 priority, ReadOptions readOptions)
   at SyncInvokePublish(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Comment: Looks like something's going wrong in your events system.

Comment: As Dominic says, this may be events system related. Can you try disabling all events system code (in the *Tridion.ContentManager.config* file) and then republishing? Are there any other error or warning messages preceding this one in the events log?

Comment: Seems issue triggering from Events system code, Is there any custom notification integrated with your event system and notification hub? Looks like notification hub page connection request got timed out. maybe worth check the connections and sessions of the notification hub if required do the IIS App pool recycle and try to test it again.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you cannot save transaction since your code is crashing at following:

```
 at Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishTransaction.Save()
```

This, based on your code, can be because of 2 things:

1. Event system code triggered on Transaction save event, or any Identifiable object save
2. Custom notification implemented which cannot be executed.

Or combination of both. In any case, it is a Connection Timeout Issue, so I would start from there.